# What caused a 45 minute gap in apache logs

Tags: apache

We have a gap in our apache logs for approximately 45 minutes, after which follows an unusually high burst of log activity.

Normally, we get a few hundred requests per hour in this time, early in the morning. But our traffic was normal, then the logs went quiet for 45 minutes (wherein people reported an inability to log in). After that, 4000 requests were written to the logs within a few minutes.

Is this consistent with an assumption that one or more runaway processes blocked the execution of other processes? Because apache logs after the process is completed, nothing got logged until the logjam was broken.

Is that a fair conclusion?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Server configuration/diagnostics are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your assumption is indeed reasonable - we had a situation like this a couple years back at the place where I work. If all apache threads are blocked by long-running operations, this kind of behaviour may appear, until at least one thread is freed up again. It doesn't need to be a "runaway" process per se, either - a heavy load, like one incurred by a DOS attack (or maybe just intensive site traffic) may also produce this "picture".

I admit to only having very basic familiarity with Apache administration, but have you checked whether your setup is has sufficient resources to handle the >usual< traffic on the affected site?

Comment: sssh. we don't talk about "sufficient" around here.

Comment: Hehe, ok - don't know much about the etiquette here yet, thanks for the tip :) Just wanted to offer something back to the comunity, considering how often I search for answers here myself ;-)